# How do any process on UILocalNotification's fireDate?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing iOS application in Swift.

Sorry, My English is very very bad.

I want to do any process on UILocalNotification's fireDate on Device is locked or app is background.

I already tried to wrote process to didReceiveLocalNotification. If device is unlocked and app is foreground, It was behavior correctly, but other cases, It does not work.

How can I implement them?

Please help me!

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) Please show us what you've tried, and look at [ask]
and [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: why, what do you want to do as a result of the fire ?

Comment: @Wain I want to play music from iPhone's music library then.

Comment: You can't do that. From docs: `specify the filename (including extension) of a sound resource in the app’s main bundle or UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName to request the default system sound.`

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

in viewController.swift[View controller from which schedule Localnotification]

```
    func scheduleLocal() {
    let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication(). currentUserNotificationSettings()

    if settings!.types == .None {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Can't schedule", message: "Either we don't have permission to schedule notifications, or we haven't asked yet.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15)
    notification.alertBody = "Hey you! Yeah you! Swipe to unlock!"
    notification.alertAction = "be awesome!"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

In ViewDidLoad()

```
    self.scheduleLocal()
```

in applicationdidFinishlaunching()

```
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes:[.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]  , categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    if let options = launchOptions {
        if let notification = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification {
            if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
                let customField1 = userInfo["CustomField1"] as! String
                // do something neat here
            }
        }
    }
```

and lastly in appdelegate.swift

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        let customField1 = userInfo["CustomField1"] as! String
        print("didReceiveLocalNotification: \(customField1)")
    }
}
```

Tried and worked on  xcode 7.3.1 swift 2.2